# How to change the column name extracted from Parse before sending to Algolia

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, algolia, back4app

I have a table in my back4app where there is a column geoloc which is an object type holding latitude and longitude values. In Algolia there is a reserved object named "_geoloc". Unfortunately Parse doesnt support column names with underscore. **My question is that how to change the column name from "geoloc" to "_geoloc" before extracting data from Parse to Algolia?**

Comment: How are currently sending the data from Parse to Algolia? Is I a trigger? Can you share the code so I can take a look and help on it?